# No Quest Marker for Certain Witcher Contracts

Tags: the-witcher-3

Trying to do the "Jenny o' the Woods" contract but the very first step is to talk to the ealdorman of Midcopse. Yet there is no quest tracker. I even went to the spot where he is supposed to be (from walkthroughs) and he doesn't even exist. Bug? I'm level 11.

Same thing for the contract "The Merry Widow." Ugh. Other contracts work, except these.

Edit: also "Mysterious Tracks." Yeah, definitely a bug. I sent a report. Let's hope I get a reply.

Comment: I had this problem but since the 1.20 update on PS4 the problem has been resolved. I've been able to complete numerous quests since, including Jenny o' the Woods.

Answer (score 1):

Been looking around internet for answer and the most conclusive thing I have heard is that it is the games way of making you explore, sounds dumb. I literally found Bolko. Found out what he looked like from researching this bs and it said 'Old Man' as the character. Talking to this character did nothing. The only thing that might be attributing to this is the fact that I remember starting this quest and talking to Bolko and then instead of talking to the witnesses around midcopse, I started another quest because I wasnt a high enough a level at the time thinking 'O it'll just start me where I left off when I am the appropriate level'. Wrong. Def a bug. Can imagine this will happen on other levels. Sorta makes me want to sell the game.

Comment: Darn. Well I submitted a bug report and forum post and all. I'll let you know if I ever find a fix.

Comment: One thing to note, I traveled to White Orchard and the quest marker appeared telling me to fast travel back, but still no marker on Bolko himself.

Comment: A marker will always show in which map a quest is, but it won't always point to a person. While playing TW3 I sometimes just searched for a walkthrough for that particular quest. But only to do the part I couldn't find. I still wanted to search myself.

Comment: It's not a quest, it's a contract. As such, the first step is to find the ealdorman. Look at any walkthrough and the marker is always there. My game has to be bugged, since now multiple contracts have the same issue and there is no mention of this online except a couple other bug reports. Explain these 3 contracts then https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8TdLYD82d7I

Comment: Happening on other quests for me aswell like 'The Merry Widow'.

Comment: Yep. And more. Here is my forum post on the matter. Happens to some PC players also. http://forums.cdprojektred.com/threads/64217-No-Quest-Marker?p=1996480#post1996480

Comment: Not sure if you're following that thread I linked, but I got a reply from CDPR about the bug. Seems they've pinpointed it and are working on it now :)